# Why does a swipe gesture stop advancing paged view controller after opening and closing side menu?

Tags: swiftui, uipageviewcontroller

My app, written in SwiftUI 2.0, is based on a UIPageViewController which displays four panels, in the common onboarding style. The user can swipe through them, or advance them using an arrow button at the bottom.

I also have a button in the upper left that opens a slide out menu, which can be closed by with a tap gesture anywhere on the interface. This is driven by changing the geometry in the swiftui "Geometry Reader", in which the page controller is embedded.

All this works correctly, except when the user closes the side window, the swipe gestures fail to activate the transition between pages. The active page slides with the swipe, but then snaps back into place. However, the arrow button still advances the UIPageViewController to the appropriate next page.

What causes the swipe gesture to become inactive after this slide out is triggered?

I've posted a small sample app isolating the issue here: https://github.com/stevepvc/Slide-and-Swipe-Concept. The code controlling the slide out menu is in "Top Content View".

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Coordinator. When you swipe between pages normally, viewControllerBefore and viewControllerAfter are being called every time along with updateUIViewController. When you click the menu button, updateUIViewController is called but the Coordinator functions are not. I don't know the  solution. Why not use the native TabView {}.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle()) instead of making your own pager?

Comment: @nicksarno the honest answer is that I began that particular project before that ApI was available! Thanks for pointing me to that solution!

Comment: No problem - hope it works. You can also try https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager.